# PropertySheet tabs close on click

Tags: c++, winapi, tabs, propertysheet

I am making a PropertySheet control with the Windows API, and for some reason tabs are closing when I click on them.

For instance, if I add 4 tabs:

[image]

Then if I click on any of those tabs except the active one (in which case nothing happens), it becomes:

[image]

And if I click on the inactive tab it disappears, leaving only one tab left.

I am creating the tabs with a dialog template in memory, created like this:

```
static const char initText[] = "Tab";

pagetemplate = (DLGTEMPLATE*)new char[sizeof(DLGTEMPLATE) + sizeof(initText) * 2];

pagetemplate->style = WS_POPUP | DS_3DLOOK | WS_BORDER | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | DS_CENTER;
pagetemplate->cdit = 0; // 0 controls
pagetemplate->cx = PROP_SM_CXDLG;
pagetemplate->cy = PROP_SM_CYDLG;

LPWORD lpword = (LPWORD)(pagetemplate + 1);
*lpword++ = 0; // no menu
*lpword++ = 0; // predefined dialog box class (by default)

MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, NULL, initText, -1, (LPWSTR)lpword, sizeof(initText) * 2);
```

Then creating the PropertySheet like this:

PROPSHEETHEADER psh;

```
SecureZeroMemory(&psh, sizeof(PROPSHEETHEADER));

psh.dwSize = sizeof(PROPSHEETHEADER);
psh.dwFlags = PSH_MODELESS | PSH_PROPSHEETPAGE | PSH_USECALLBACK;
psh.pszCaption = "Window";
psh.nPages = 1;
psh.nStartPage = 0;

PROPSHEETPAGE pages[1];

SecureZeroMemory(pages, sizeof(PROPSHEETPAGE));

pages[0].dwSize = sizeof(PROPSHEETPAGE);
pages[0].dwFlags = PSP_DLGINDIRECT;
pages[0].pResource = CGTabWindow::pagetemplate;
pages[0].pfnDlgProc = DialogProc;
pages[0].lParam = (LPARAM)this;

psh.ppsp = (PROPSHEETPAGE*)&pages;

propsheet = PropertySheet(&psh);
```

And adding the four pages like this:

```
PROPSHEETPAGE page;

SecureZeroMemory(&page, sizeof(PROPSHEETPAGE));

page.dwSize = sizeof(PROPSHEETPAGE);
page.dwFlags = PSP_DLGINDIRECT;
page.pResource = CGTabWindow::pagetemplate;
page.pfnDlgProc = DialogProc;
page.lParam = (LPARAM)this;

HPROPSHEETPAGE hpage = CreatePropertySheetPage(&page);

SendMessage((HWND)propsheet, PSM_ADDPAGE, NULL, (LPARAM)hpage);
```

And finally, here's my DialogProc:

```
BOOL CALLBACK  DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
 cout << "hey" << endl;

     switch (iMsg)
  {
          case WM_INITDIALOG :
               return TRUE ;


    case WM_COMMAND:
               switch (LOWORD (wParam))
      {
     case ID_EDIT :
       return TRUE;
     case ID_HELP :
       return TRUE;
              case IDOK :
                         EndDialog (hDlg, 0) ;
                return TRUE ;
      }

              break ;
     }
     return FALSE;
}
```

But for some reason, "hey" is never displayed. Also, sending the PSM_INDEXTOHWND with any index always returns NULL. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was because you must have at least 1 control in the dialog template.